# Why use a mutual has_one relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

Looking at the ActiveRecord has_one and has_many relations in Rails, this is probably a general (and very likely obvious) question.

If I have two tables, say Husbands and Wives, and it is a monogamous all married couples database, then each husband has a wife, and each wife has a husband. So it would make sense to treat this as a single table of couples.

Why would anyone want to have two tables where both tables have a has_one relation with the other, instead of combining them as a single table?

- Could there be any efficiency gain?
- Can it cover some case I haven't figured out?

Comment: This would only make sense to do if you wanted to only ever deal with the couples as a whole; you had no interest in the individual people. What if you wanted to query all *people* that had some characteristic, regardless of gender? What if each person then had some association to other objects in the system?

Comment: why not the single table? who require the separate tables?

Comment: you can just use inheritance for Husband, and Wife from Person, then use `type` field, and just Husband and Wife via spouse_id

Comment: also, what happens when your next requirement is to support same-sex marriage?

Comment: @sevenseacat he can just refuse to support smae-sex marriage.

Comment: also, what happens when you have other requirements to model about the relationship between two people? Divorce? Remarrying? A relationship between entities is just that - a relationship.

Answer (score 4):

It depends.

If:

1. you are only interested in the couples,
2. individual people don't hold any data,
3. everyone HAS a spouse,

then, yes, using a single table might make sense.

However, if any of the above is false, you will want to use individual records.

You should declare the associations like this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :gender, presence: :true

  belongs_to :wife, -> { where gender: "F" },
                    foreign_key: :wife_id,
                          class: "Person"


  has_one :husband, -> { where gender: "M" },
                    foreign_key: :wife_id,
                          class: "Person"

end
```

However, if you want the *couple* record to also hold some data, you might be better off with this kind of implementation:

```
class Marriage < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :husband_id, presence: true
  validates :wife_id, presence: true

  belongs_to :husband, class: "Person"                
  belongs_to :wife, class: "Person"
end



class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :marriage

  has_one :husband, though: :marriage
  has_one :wife, though: :marriage
end
```

Although you should be aware that if a `person = Person.find()` is a, say, `wife`, and you call `person.wife`, it might return itself.

Answer (score 3):

you can just use inheritance for `Husband`, and `Wife` from `Person`, then use `type` field, and just relate the `Husband` and `Wife` via spouse_id.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_protected :spouse_id
end

class Husband < Person
   belongs_to :wife, foreign_key: :spouse_id
end

class Wife < Person
   belongs_to :husband, foreign_key: :spouse_id
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`belongs_to`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association), it's far simpler. `@Малъ Скрылевъ`'s answer is right, but I wanted to show you a simple way to achieve it:

```
#app/models/spouse.rb
Class Spouse < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :spouse, foreign_key: "spouse_id", class_name: "Spouse"
end
```

This will give you a table:

```
spouses
id | spouse_id | name | created_at | updated_at
```

This will allow you to perform:

```
@person = Spouse.find params[:id]
@person.spouse # -> finds by spouse_id
```

If you wanted to determine by husband / wife, you'd use the [STI](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance) answer from `Малъ Скрылевъ`

Answer (score 0):

I learned from the answers, but most of them took my example of couples too literally. It was meant just an example. The question was about any A has_one B, B has_one A relationship.

sevenseacat's third comment "A relationship between entities is just that - a relationship" really gave me the idea about the second part to my question, namely "some case that I haven't figured out".

> While the husband wife relationship is a reflexive relation, not every relationship has to be that way. For example we could have the relation: A "is most attracted to" B, which is not necessarily reflexive. B might find some other individual most attractive. So even though each A has_one B, and each B has_one A, this relationship does not necessarily create pairs. In plain English, "being attracted to" is not necessarily a mutual relationship (a sad fact of life that many people have a hard time accepting).

For the first part of the question, in terms of efficiency, a point hinted at in some of the answers was just because you can put them in one table doesn't mean you must.

> If we are usually just interested in individuals, and only rarely in the spouses, then having one table with long rows would probably be inefficient. On the other hand if usually we are interested in data about both spouses at the same time then combining the tables might be better.

As the other answers mention,

> when we have both tables being similar, except for gender, then having a single table for people, has its own benefits, and a number of interesting ways to implement this option are given.